# Are there any different ways to theorise that atoms exist?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, brownian-motion

I have read that Albert Einstein and some notable others theoretically proved atoms through Brownian motion. Are there any other perspectives or methods to theoretically or experimentally prove that atoms exist in contrast with Brownian motion? If so, how? (a link to a research paper will be helpful)

Thank you

Comment: Everyone with an ion accelerator can experimentally show they exist…

Comment: "theoretically proved "  you mean "modeled mathematically the observations".

Answer (score 2):

An atom is the smallest unit of ordinary matter that forms a chemical element. Other than Brownian motion, two of the most important theories to support the atomic hypothesis are:

- Dalton's law of multiple proportions (1800): Dalton noticed that if two elements can be combined to form a number of different compounds (e.g. different oxides of tin), then the ratios of the masses in the various compounds will be integers.
- Statistical mechanics (late 19th century): Thermodynamics - the study of heat, energy, work and the relations between them - was put on a rigorous theoretical foundation using statistical arguments that involved a large number of particles (~10^23). Maxwell, Boltzmann, Gibbs and others who developed statistical mechanics were convinced by the existence of atoms because they were able to derive things like the ideal gas law and the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution using atomistic arguments.

In the 20th century, we discovered that there are many subatomic particles inside an atom. You may want to look into the [Standard Model of Particle Physics](https://home.cern/science/physics/standard-model).

I think it's important to realise that physics - and science in general - cannot prove the existence of atoms. However, theoretical arguments, backed up by experiment, can provide overwhelming evidence to support an atomic theory. For a popular account of this idea, see this [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/12/14/theres-no-such-thing-as-proof-in-the-scientific-world-theres-only-evidence/?sh=56da0c155392).

N.B. My answer largely paraphrases Wikipedia's article on [atomic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_theory).